# why flask ignores fragment identifier?

Tags: python, flask

I have some codes that gets some input from url and I run my functions on this input, here is part of my code:

```
@app.route('/input', methods=['POST', 'GET']) def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        user_input = request.args.get('text')
        return myfunc(user_input)
```

when I enter for example this input:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/input?text=some text
```

I will get `some text` as user input.

problem shows up when the user enters some input containing fragment identifier... then the text after that identifier will be ignored

for example from this input:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/input?text=some text#blah blah blah
```

I just get `some text` and not whole user request as `some text#blah blah blah`

Any idea how can I get whole text?

Comment: how can I extract them on the client and pass them to the server via a query parameter or part of the URL path? @ABDULNIYASPM

Comment: How is the string `some text#blah blah blah` getting added to the URL? Most likely that is where your error is: you're probably not performing URL escaping correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not pass "#" in to querystring value. You have to replace # with its UTF-8 value (%23). See the example below

**http://127.0.0.1:5000/input?text=some text%23blah blah blah**

It works for me.

Comment: UTF-8 value for some other characters are here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape-encodeuri-lower-ascii.htm

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use send values after `#` to a server side, because they are browser specific and are cropped before sending.

You could change your querystring to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/input?text=some text&fragment=blah blah blah` on your frontend